# Square order confirmation email - Square API with 123Formbuilder

Tags: square, square-connect

I've used the Square API integrated into a form built in 123formbuilder. Is there any way to:

1. modify the content and themes of the auto generated order confirmation email sent by Square from no-reply@squareup.com to the customers email address? A screenshot of the email is:

   [image: Square Order Confirmation Email]
2. Stop the auto generated order confirmation email sent by Square to the customer from no-reply@squareup.com and instead have the receipt email sent automatically in the format set in the Square dashboard via Accounts & Setting --> Receipt upon successful payment being processed? An example of the auto generated receipt email is:

   [image: Auto Generated Square Receipt]

Comment: Just saw your question now. Sorry, if it came late, but did you try using the built-in Square integration on 123FormBuilder? It provides an option to send a confirmation message after the payment has been processed, and you can add a custom email address.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither of those options are currently possible. 123FormBulder utilizes Square Checkout (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/checkout/overview) which isn't customizable since it's hosted by Square.